# Returning from an Exception

Tags: php, exception

This is probably going to sound like a sci-fi request, though – is there a way to return to the beginning of the `try {}` block where Exception was thrown from within the `catch() {}` block?

Here is an example:

```
try
{
    // make OAuth request
}
catch(OAuthException $e)
{
    // if(){}
    // If tells me that the Exception was thrown because the access token is expired
    // I have alternative access token (that's always up to date, but there is a catch why I void using it)
    // I set it as a new access token and want to repeat the try {} block
}
```

Obviously `goto` could do it, though, I am looking if there is a more sophisticated approach.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a separate function then calling it again when you catch the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the code up inside a function and call the same function from the catch section

```
function remotePost($accessToken){

  try{

  }catch(OAuthException $e){
  //the one used is not alternative token and if there is an alternative access token
    return remotePost($alternativeAccessToken);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A `while` loop.

```
do {
  $ok = false;
  try {
    // something
    $ok = true;
  } catch (...) {
    // something
  }
} while (!$ok);
```

AksharRoop's and Broncha's solution is also nice, especially if you have a limited number of backup plans (i.e. for the specific scenario you describe). Using `while` is somewhat more general.

Comment: Yours is an answer to be selected ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Move your try block to a separate function so that you can call it again with a new token.

```
try
{
    MakeAuthRequest(token);
}
catch(OAuthException $e)
{
    if (failedDueToToken)
    {
        MakeAuthRequest(newToken);
    }
}
```